# how to show menu item on button click on toolstrip

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am working on an application where I have to load menus on the tool strip dynamically from database. So far I have created the menu and its working, now I have to display that menu on tool strip button click event.

Here is my code:

```
private void toolstripform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.IsMdiContainer = true;
    this.Controls.Add(toolStrip1);
    string slctcmd = string.Format("SELECT * FROM MNU_PARENT where MENUPARVAL = 2 ");
    DataTable dt = qc.DataReaderTable(slctcmd);
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem MnuStripItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(dr["MAINMNU"].ToString());
        SubMenu(MnuStripItem, dr["MENUPARVAL"].ToString());
        toolStrip1.Items.Add(MnuStripItem);
    }
}
public void SubMenu(ToolStripMenuItem mnu, string submenu)
{
    string slctcmd = string.Format("SELECT FRM_NAME FROM MNU_SUBMENU WHERE MENUPARVAL='" + submenu + "'");
    DataTable dt = qc.DataReaderTable(slctcmd);
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem SSMenu = new ToolStripMenuItem(dr["FRM_NAME"].ToString(), null, new EventHandler(ChildClick));
        mnu.DropDownItems.Add(SSMenu);
    }
}
private void ChildClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("You have Clicked ", sender.ToString(), " Menu"), "Menu Items Event",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    string slctcmd = string.Format("SELECT FRM_CODE FROM MNU_SUBMENU WHERE FRM_NAME= '" + sender.ToString() + "'");
    DataTable dtransaction = qc.DataReaderTable(slctcmd);
    Assembly frmAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Application.ExecutablePath);
    foreach(Type type in frmAssembly.GetTypes())
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(type.Name);
        if (type.BaseType == typeof (Form))
        {
            if (type.Name == dtransaction.Rows[0][0].ToString())
            {
                Form frmShow = (Form) frmAssembly.CreateInstance(type.ToString());
                // then when you want to close all of them simple call the below code
                foreach(Form form in this.MdiChildren)
                {
                    form.Close();
                }
                frmShow.MdiParent = this;
                frmShow.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
                //frmShow.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                //frmShow.ControlBox = false;
                frmShow.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's currently showing this:
[image: currently showing this..]

I would like it to show like this:
[image: I want like this..]

Answer (score 0):

```
     MnuStripItem.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(mainM_MouseDown);
```

---

```
    private void mainM_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       //if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            cMenuS_main_it.Show(Cursor.Position);
        }
    }
```